# Enzyme shallow renderer returns null node element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a problem with Enzyme shallow renderer. My `wrapper.root.node` returning me null even for simple div element.

```
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <div>asd</div>
        );
```

And here is ShallowWrapper object. Node element is null, but unrendered property contains normal rendered object. Why is that ?

```
ShallowWrapper {
  "complexSelector": ComplexSelector {
    "buildPredicate": [Function],
    "childrenOfNode": [Function],
    "findWhereUnwrapped": [Function],
  },
  "length": 1,
  "node": null,
  "nodes": Array [
    null,
  ],
  "options": Object {},
  "renderer": ReactShallowRenderer {
    "_instance": null,
    "getRenderOutput": [Function],
    "render": [Function],
  },
  "root": [Circular],
  "unrendered": <div>
    asd
</div>,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem caused by jest 'react-dom' mock :

```
jest.mock('react-dom')
```

Problem solved by moving unit test into other file.